# Iphone 5S safari webpage zoom issue

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, metatag

My scenario is I have iphone 5S device and safari browser. In this browser I opened a site (this site is included in bootstrap responsive also) with include below meta tag code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

If I opened the site with zoom in mode. everything is fine.

My problem is if open any other page of the same site it is showing zoom in view, but my requirement is if I open any page it will show normal view not in a zoom view. How can I do?

Shall I add any code in the meta tag? please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<meta id="id" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
})
```

Comment: if you want zoom them remove this when page load

Comment: i am not understand how i remove when page load time.